# What is equals of Visual Studio .Net [DebuggerStepThrough] in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I want to ignore some lines while debugging in Qt.
I know I can do it in Visual Studio .Net with `[DebuggerStepThrough]` 
http://www.debuggerstepthrough.com/2013/01/some-good-to-know-c-attributes.html
but I wanna know the equivalent of this code in Qt, C++.

Is there code in Qt for this purpose, if not, how I can do it in Qt Creator?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Qt or Qt Creator, it will be a feature of your debugger - which you haven't specified.

Comment: @cmannett85: Thanks for comment, as far as I know Qt or Qt creator has just one debugger, `GDB`. I'm new on Qt, I wanna ignore some codes in debug mode, How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows with Visual Studio compiler you could use the following:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //code to run at any build
    foo();

    //code to run only in debug build
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    bar();
    #endif

    //code to run only in release build
    #ifndef _DEBUG
    baz();
    #endif
}
```

I hope this helps.